# JS Regex: Cannot use captures when using global?

Tags: javascript, regex

It seems that I cannot use captures when using the global option?

```
var regex = /^\s*\[(.*)\]:\s+(\S+)(\s+"(.*)"\s*)?$/gm;
var matches = textareaText.match(regex);
for (var i in matches) {
  console.log(matches[i]);
}
```

I just get

```
match 0: [1]: http://google.com
match 1: [2]: http://test.com/example.png "hello world"
```

Without any captures like when I just use `m` swicth

```
match 0: [1]: http://google.com
match 1: 1
match 2: http://google.com
match 3: undefined
match 4: undefined
match index: 0
match input: [1]: http://google.com [2]: http://test.com/example.png "hello world"
```

But with just this, its just the 1st match, I want all. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `String.match`, you can `RegExp` object's `exec` method and use `regex.lastIndex` to continue searching. Look here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Here's a jsfiddle with a simple example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jqJDU/3/

Here's a separate example of `lastIndex`:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/regexp_lastindex.htm

Comment: I don't really understand why that works. won't `while (true)` give an infinite loop? You didn't break out of the loop anywhere. also can I say `rma` everytime you reference rma. I tried to code in in another manner I thought I will understand better, but got an infinite loop. why does this fail -> Warning: will crash browser -> http://jsfiddle.net/jqJDU/2/

Comment: ok, I found the problem. I should something more like http://jsfiddle.net/WcwKU/ the main diff, `str.substring(match.index + match[0].length)`. I can just use `match.index` no need for `regex.lastIndex`

Comment: Sorry, missed that - here's the correct version: http://jsfiddle.net/jqJDU/3/. `rma` becomes null, so it bombs out, that's why the above "works". Anyway, your solution works fine, too.